# Why is $v_\infty$ a valuation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm sure this is a really dumb question (and I've tried to find a duplicate but could not), but I'm confused why $v_{\infty}(\frac{f}{g}) = \deg(f) - \deg(g)$ is a valuation at all. Is $0 = v_\infty(1) = v_\infty((x-1) + (2-x)) \geq \min(v_\infty(x-1), v_\infty(2-x)) = 1$ not a contradiction?

Comment: it's $- \deg$ that is a valuation, not $\deg$

Comment: Ah, that must have been a typo then. Thanks, that makes so much more sense!